# how to access records without read prmission?

Tags: sharing

OWD of an object is set as private.
Manager with role does not have read access to the object.How to open up records of the object to the manager?

Comment: Give the manage's profile read access to the object and if you have Access granted by hierarchy, records owned by people in roles under the manager will be viewable by the manager. But I sense there is more to the story or you would not be asking the question. Can you be a bit more detailed on the problem and why the standard way of doing it does not work for you?

Comment: what if the managers profile cant be modified? is there any other way he can still view the records?

Comment: @roshni Consider using a permission set, then. It will affect just that one user.

Comment: permission sets to give read access to manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the manager to a public group and create criteria-based or role- based sharing rules on the object to share records with the public group.

This is assuming she has object level read permission. Your question says without read permission on object but the problem sounds like the manager doesn't have record level access.

Permission sets and profiles handle object CRED perms, while owd and sharing handles record access.  So you may also need to great R on tbe object via a permission set.

There is a video series called "who sees what" that is quite good at explaining this.

https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2012/06/announcing-the-who-sees-what-series.html

Answer (score 0):

change his permission set / change his role and put him on that hierarchy level where he can see the records.